# how do i set up perl on my mac?

Tags: perl, macos, cgi, terminal

I have osx snowleopard and I know perl is suppose to come installed but when i type perl-v into terminal i get command not found. pleas help

```
 Last login: Mon Mar 14 22:56:37 on ttys000
 arroyos-macbook-pro:~ arroyo$ perl-v
 -bash: perl-v: command not found
 arroyos-macbook-pro:~ arroyo$
```

Comment: whats perl-v ? perl is command **perl**

Comment: Perl 5.10.0 is shipped with 10.6. OS X Lion will probably ship with 5.12.3. The command to run perl is `perl` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a space between perl and -v? if you dont, you need a space:

```
perl -v
```